# Were there any ancient Buddhist Universities, outside of India?

Tags: learning-materials, university

There were at least 22 universities according to this --
[Ancient Buddhist
Universities in
India](https://mu.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/2016-Ancient-Buddhist-University-in-India-compressed.pdf) by Dr. Sandesh Wagh, Mumbai University:

> - In contrast to this with the rise of Buddhism in
>   India, there arose many center's of learning which
>   did not exist before.
> - Buddhist monks could opt for a life of meditation in
>   the forests, or a life of teaching, preaching,
>   propagating the Dhamma as a result of these
>   activities, seats of learning arose.
> - These seats of monastic learning (Pirivenas)
>   gradually developed and some of them became fullfledged universities.
>
> 22 Major Ancient Buddhist University
>
> - These organized institutions in the form of
>   Monasteries, Viharas and Universities formed the
>   spinal cord of the country.
> - Well established regular educational institutions
>   were founded during Buddhist period.
> - Gradually big shrines and hermitages began to
>   function as educational institutions.
> - With the passage of time these places assumed
>   the status of institutions imparting primary and
>   higher education.
>
> 1. Takshila Buddhist University
> 2. Nalanda Buddhist University
> 3. Vallabhi Buddhist University
> 4. Vikramshila Buddhist University
> 5. Teleadaka Buddhist University
> 6. Odantapuri Buddhist University
> 7. Sompura Buddhist University
> 8. Jaggadala Buddhist University
> 9. Phushpagiri Buddhist University
> 10. Nagaarjunakonda Buddhist University
> 11. Kashmir or Shardha Buddhist University
> 12. Ujjain Buddhist University
> 13. Nabadwip Buddhist University
> 14. Tawang Buddhist University
> 15. Shrangiri Buddhist University
> 16. Samye Buddhist University
> 17. PanditVihara Buddhist University
> 18. Gunshila Buddhist Women University
> 19. Kashi Buddhist University
> 20. Kanchipuram Buddhist University
> 21. Kururshetra Buddhist University
> 22. Kanheri Rock-cut Buddhist University

However were there any other universities outside India (the Indian subcontinent as we know it now), especially China, Korea, southeast Asia?

There were lot of Scholars who travelled to and from India, do any of their travelogues mention any of these universities?

Comment: That link does not open for me.

Comment: its a large file it takes sometime to load, you can google Ancient-Buddhist-University-in-India- mostly should be on first page, at least in India.

Comment: @AndreiVolkov I quoted almost all the text in it, it's formatted like a slide-deck (i.e. PowerPoint presentation) and is mostly 80 photographs of the remains of these places.

Comment: I am also interested to know what subjects were taught in these universities , the wikipedia article about vikramshila(An Indian University) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vikramashila mentions subjects like  philosophy, grammar, metaphysics, Indian logic etc were taught  in Vikramshila.

Answer (score 2):

There are folklore regarding a massive University like establishment in [Anuradhapura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anuradhapura_Maha_Viharaya), Sri Lanka which was later burned down by the invading armies.

In Sri Lanka the Buddhist education was centralized around establishments named [Pirivena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirivena). The [Sunethradevi Pirivena](http://buddhistplacesinsrilanka.weebly.com/sunetradevi-pirivena.html) is believed to be more than 600 years old.